# Php transform one-to-many relation result set to nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql

This is a php(and/or Mysql) question. Table [A] has a one to many relation with Table [B]. What's the best way to extract a result set that has rows only from Table [A] and nests records from table [B] as an array in the result set? Is there a simple way/function to do this in php (or mysql)?

Thank you!

E.g. Simplified description of the problem, details are omitted. Assume Table [A] *id* field is Primary key and Table[B] has a foreign key to Table [A] as column *a_id*.

```
Table [A]
id->1, value1...
id->2, value2...

Table [B]
id->X, a_id->1, valueA,....
id->Y, a_id->1, valueB,.... 
id->Z, a_id->1, valueC,....
id->U, a_id->2, valueD,....
id->T, a_id->2, valueE,....

Simple join select between Table[A] and Table[B], joined by Table [A]'s id to Table [B]'s a_id column. ResultSet has Table [A] id column and Table [B] id columns in array.

Result set;
row#1 => 1, {X,Y,Z}, ....
row#2 => 2, {U,T}, .....
```

Comment: Take a moment to read up on MySQL's GROUP BY functions, specifically GROUP_CONCAT() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat OR you could just do your JOIN query and nest your data in php. Multiple ways to wok-a-dog, just depends on what you want to do in the end with the data

Comment: Thank you, "GROUP_CONCAT" is exactly what I needed! If you provide an answer, I'll accept it.