# Best way to build a deep tree from MySQL results?

Tags: mysql, node.js, algorithm

My tree structure is as follows:

- Book

  - Chapters

    - Sections

      - Components

        - Images

My results are based off of a few outer joins:

- book_id
- book_name
- chapter_id
- chapter_name
- section_id
  ...
  until images.

What is the best way to build a tree structure from the linear dataset returned from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373258/php-transform-one-to-many-relation-result-set-to-nested-arrays).

There are three basic options and one pedantic one.

**First Option**:

```
SELECT * FROM Book b JOIN Chapters c USING (book_id) JOIN Sections s USING (chapter_id) ...
```

With the results from the above query, you can easily make a nested object by reading the columns and traversing the root object. It's trivial, but the amount of duplicated data from the DB may cause performance issues depending on your use case.

**Second Option**:

```
SELECT * FROM Book WHERE (your filters here);
```

With the query result, create a map of BookId -> Book Object, e.g.

```
for (result : results) { books[result.book_id] = new Book(result); }
```

With that, make another query:

```
SELECT * FROM Chapter WHERE book_id IN (book ids you collected earlier)
```

And continue doing this, mapping as you go. It *can* be quicker and more efficient than the first option, but the amount of complicated code might make the performance gains no longer worth it.

**Third Option**:

Use an ORM, such as [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). It will use some efficient combination of my first and second options. Probably. But it will abstract the pain away from you, as the user.

**Pedantic Option**:

Depending on your use case, MySQL may not be right for hosting this kind of data. How often do you need to return an entire Book object, rather than the pieces that the user needs right now? Do you frequently filter books based on their images? Maybe a JSON-based store like MongoDB could be helpful, or perhaps you could store Sections, Components, and Images in a single BLOB column on the Chapters table. Again, it depends a lot on your use case.